# Contraction Mapping Theorem: please explain complete metric space under operator and contraction

Tags: vector-spaces, metric-spaces, operator-theory, machine-learning

> Contraction Mapping Theorem:
>
> For any metric space V that is complete (i.e. closed) under an operator T(v), where T is a γ-contraction, T converges to a unique fixed point and at a linear convergence rate of γ.

This is from field of artificial intelligence, called reinforcement learning, but I'm confused by some pure math terminology.

1. I know that metric space being complete means that any Cauchy sequence converges, but what means that it's complete under operator?
2. I read [this](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Contraction_(operator_theory)) on contraction in operator theory, is this correct interpretation of  γ-contraction?

Comment: Your source is muddled.  "Operator theory" usually carries a  connotation of a linear topological vector space lurking nearby, which contradicts "any metric space".  The better Wikipedia  info scoop is probably the one on the [Banach fixed point theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Banach_fixed-point_theorem).  In general: contraction yields a Cauchy sequence, and without completeness one does not know a limit exits.

Comment: In agreement with @kimchilover, I would think that the correct wording would have been something like “…that is complete, and closed under an operator $T$ which is a $\gamma$-contraction, $T$ has a unique fixed point…”. The point is that completeness is a property of the space $V$, while contractivity is a property of the transformation $T$.

Comment: Whoever wrote that paragraph seems confused.